# What is the best way to manage my savings and possibly increase my cash flow despite inflation in Egypt?

Tags: investing, inflation, hedging, hyperinflation, egypt

With the very quickly rising prices in Egypt, What is the best way to manage my savings and possibly increase my cash flow?

I’ve also got some ideas, Are they good or not?

Ideas that I have:

- Work as a freelancer
- Change some of my savings into dollars and putting them into the money markets
- Purchase Real Estate